# Code given in MATLAB documentation for montage function returning errors

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to display a montage of images in MATLAB, where each image is an N x M array and K images are stored as an N x M x K array.

MATLAB returns the errors:

```
Error using images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 115)
Multi-plane image inputs must be RGB images of size MxNx3.

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams (line 27)
common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in imshow (line 240)
      images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs({'Parent','Border','Reduce'},preparsed_varargin{:});

Error in montage (line 152)
    hh = imshow(bigImage, displayRange,parentArgs{:});
```

These exact errors persist when I copy-paste and run the code supplied the [MATLAB documentation for the montage function](https://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html#mw_e2ac5b94-804f-49d1-855c-0f6509a321ba), included here:

```
img1 = imread('AT3_1m4_01.tif');
img2 = imread('AT3_1m4_02.tif');
img3 = imread('AT3_1m4_03.tif');
img4 = imread('AT3_1m4_04.tif');
multi = cat(3,img1,img2,img3,img4);

montage(multi);
```

This code is supposed to create a montage from an N x M x K array in the same manner as the original code I am troubleshooting, and fails to in the same manner.

Does anyone else receive these errors from this code? Can someone tell me how to adjust this code to produce a montage of images as demonstrated in the documentation example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a version error. Are you running Matlab 2018a? That is the version which the documentation is for. I would fancy a guess that an older version of Matlab used a different interface.

I would try typing

```
help montage
```

in your Matlab. Perhaps there are some addition tips there.

Comment: Thank you! You're right! I'm running 2016b. When I type 'help montage', I can see that the syntax for the equivalent use case is slightly different: if the images are grayscale, they should be input as an N x M x 1 x K array. After making this adjustment, the code works!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

> montage(I) displays all the frames of a multiframe image array I. A
>   multiframe image array can be a sequence of binary, grayscale, or
>   truecolor images. A binary or grayscale image sequence must be an
>   M-by-N-by-K or an M-by-N-by-1-by-K array. A truecolor image sequence
>   must be an M-by-N-by-3-by-K array.

however the `M-by-N-by-K` does not seem to work. But the `M-by-N-by-1-by-K` does.

Therefore

```
multi = cat(4,img1,img2,img3,img4);
```